# AfxGetAppName() returns garbage characters

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the following line of code in my application:

```
CString strAppName = AfxGetAppName();
```

Sometimes it fills `strAppName` up with garbage characters, and I can't figure out why.

Anyone have any ideas?

TIA.

Comment: Are you sure that `strAppName` filled with garbage characters? Some incorrect code after that string could lead to corrupting `strAppName`.

Comment: I am positive. I'm running the app in debug mode, and AfxGetAppName() returns garbage. Alternately, maybe it doesn't return anything, and there is garbage already there.

Comment: To find out how m_lpszCurrentAppName is initialized you could try to add data breakpoint as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is possible if you change `m_pszAppName` manually.

> At the very beginning of application initialization, `AfxWinInit` calls `CWinApp::SetCurrentHandles`, which caches the current value of the `m_pszAppName` pointer as follows:
>   `pModuleState->m_lpszCurrentAppName = m_pszAppName;`
>
> That is, the module state struct holds a copy of the `m_pszAppName` pointer. If you change `m_pszAppName` in `InitInstance` as adviced in MSDN, you still have the old pointer value in `pModuleState->m_lpszCurrentAppName`. The `AfxGetAppName()` function returns `AfxGetModuleState()->m_lpszCurrentAppName`.

You could add [data breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx) on m_lpszCurrentAppName and on `m_pszAppName`. It is initialized in `<...>\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\appinit.cpp` file. You'll see what is going on with that variable and who's trying to change it.

Comment: My application does not change `m_pszAppName`. It changes some registry keys though, could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't think that changing registry keys could implicitly change `m_pszAppName`.